# Change Opacity in pressed state of image

Tags: android, android-layout

I using an imageview for button.
For normal state it is simple red color image with text on it  , in pressed state i want to change the opacity of image.

[image]

Now in press state i want to decrease the opacity of this image . 
To do so the option i know is 
       1. create an other image with required opacity and use selector to get the effect
       2. use color codes for both the states in selector ;
But here i already have one image state as image , for the next state i want to decrease the opacity in this image only .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```java
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (v == button) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      v.setAlpha(0.5f);
    } else {
      v.setAlpha(1f);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi i saw your blog great , you have one toogle button post , can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986875/how-to-move-toogle-button-label-move-to-right-side

Comment: I think `v.setAlpha(.5f);` accepts `int` now so the right way is `v.setAlpha(128);` and `v.setAlpha(1f);` will be `v.setAlpha(255);`

Answer (score 2):

You may use a flag to store state and call this to change opacity:

```
button.getBackground().setAlpha(60);
```

Comment: i know this but on when pressed state is removed it should automatically be again to normal, how to implement this using selector

Comment: Then you may use a checkbox, not the button. It supports click listeners, in which you can check current state.

Comment: If you need the opacity change during one user interaction, then use @selva solution. Checkbox will be in help, if you need to remain your button pressed for a while (for example, until async call is finished).

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `ImageView` class i.e. `AlphaImageView` that extends from `ImageView` and override the `setPressed()` method like so:

```
@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    super.setPressed(pressed);
    setAlpha(pressed ? 0.5f : 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change a little bit a correct answer above to make it work as I need: when you cancel a touch only the opacity should change, it should not blink.

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(viewId);
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (v == button) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      v.setAlpha(0.5f);
    } else {
      v.setAlpha(1f);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use android selector(It does not require you to create custom control or logic)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:alpha="0.3" android:src="@drawable/your_cancel_button_image" />
    </item>
    //other selector states 
</selector>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and it works for drawableLeft, etc. as well. Anyone knows if there are drawbacks or quirks to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(viewId);     
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
     if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         v.setAlpha(.5f);
    } 
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        v.setAlpha(1f);
    }
    return true;    //make shure to return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My class for change `ImageView` alpha when pressed

```
public class PressableImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    private static final float DEFAULT_ALPHA_WHEN_PRESS = 0.5f;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ALPHA = 1f;

    public PressableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PressableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PressableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void refresh() {
        if (isPressed()) {
            setAlpha(DEFAULT_ALPHA_WHEN_PRESS);
            invalidate();
            return;
        }
        setAlpha(DEFAULT_ALPHA);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        super.setPressed(pressed);
        refresh();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            setPressed(true);
        } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            setPressed(false);
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            boolean isInside = (x > 0 && x < getWidth() && y > 0 && y < getHeight());
            if(isInside){
                performClick();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using

```
<....PressableImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
```