# How to move Toggle Button Label to right side

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

Hi i am using a toggle button , in xml, and have set text as  allSchools

My code is

```
 <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/execute_Search"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="All Schools" />
```

It is displaying the toggle button on the right and the label on the left.

I want it to be the other way around.

Comment: Just split them. Don't set any text in Switch-widget and create TextView field in the place you need it to be.

Comment: did you try with padding ?android:paddingLeft=""  android:paddingRight=""